# How to find lines containing two strings together in Linux?

Tags: linux, string, file, search

I want to display lines that contain "addUser" and "2012-08-03" strings together on the same line in a Linux file. How to do this?

Comment: grep addUser | grep "<user>2012-08-03</user>" filename, but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep addUser filename | grep "<user>2012-08-03</user>"
```

Comment: why isn't addUser between double quotes?

Comment: You need to quotes (single or double) only if string have bash special characters. Otherwise they are optional.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/addUser/ && /2012-08-03/' < file
```

or

```
grep addUser < file | grep 2012-08-03
```

or

```
sed -n 's@addUser@&@p' < file | sed -n 's@2012-08-03@&@p'
```

or

```
ruby -e 'File.readlines( "file" ).each {|l| puts l if l =~ /addUser/ and l =~ /2012-08-03/ }'
```

Comment: Thanks, if strings are: "<user>2012-08-03</user>" and "addUser", then how?

Answer (score 1):

command in linux

echo "adduser 2012-08-03 " > data.txt

to see the contents of data.txt file type
cat data.txt

or vi data.txt